# Simple C# ASP.NET Cache Implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I need to build up a `List<object>` and cache the list and be able to append to it.  I also need to be able to blow it away easily and recreate it.  What is a simple way to accomplish this?

Comment: Keep in mind your List will not be thread safe.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;

public class MyListCache
{
    private List<object> _MyList = null;
    public List<object> MyList {
        get {
            if (_MyList == null) {
                _MyList = (HttpContext.Current.Cache["MyList"] as List<object>);
                if (_MyList == null) {
                    _MyList = new List<object>();
                    HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("MyList", _MyList);
                }
            }
            return _MyList;
        }
        set {
            HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("MyList", _MyList);
        }
    }

    public void ClearList() {
        HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove("MyList");
    }
}
```

As for how to use.....

```
// Get an instance
var listCache = new MyListCache();

// Add something
listCache.MyList.Add(someObject);

// Enumerate
foreach(var o in listCache.MyList) {
  Console.WriteLine(o.ToString());
}  

// Blow it away
listCache.ClearList();
```

Comment: Well... serviceable.  But I would make some changes.  Primarily, I would always return a valid list. If it doesn't exist, create a new empty collection and cache it, rather than just returning whatever is in Cache["MyList"], which might be null.

Comment: Yes Bryan, this example is quite simple. - But I took your suggestion to heart and updated my sample. Thanks.

Comment: In many/most real world scenarios you'll want to flush changes to some kind of persistant storage.

Answer (score 2):

This Tutorial is what I found to be helpful

- [**ASP.NET Caching Features**](http://authors.aspalliance.com/aspxtreme/webapps/aspcachingfeatures.aspx)

Here is a sample

```
List<object> list = new List<Object>();

Cache["ObjectList"] = list;                 // add
list = ( List<object>) Cache["ObjectList"]; // retrieve
Cache.Remove("ObjectList");                 // remove
```

Comment: link is broken :(

Answer (score 0):

The caching parts of ["Tracing and Caching Provider Wrappers for Entity Framework"](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers-c0b88f32), while not simple, are still a pretty good review of some useful things to think about with caching.

Specifically, the two classes `InMemoryCache` and `AspNetCache` and their associated tests:

- [ICache](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers-c0b88f32/sourcecode?fileId=19054&pathId=176281961)
- [InMemoryCache](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers-c0b88f32/sourcecode?fileId=19054&pathId=1876572097) and [tests](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers-c0b88f32/sourcecode?fileId=19054&pathId=1078284576)
- [AspNetCache](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers-c0b88f32/sourcecode?fileId=19054&pathId=163137585)

Similar to what the question did, you could wrap `HttpRuntime.Cache` or `HttpContext.Current.Items` or `HttpContext.Current.Cache` in an implementation of `ICache`.