# Check for new data after a certain time frame

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, sql, web-services

Right now I'm using a 3rd party provider to get some data. Every time I call the service I need to pay a small fee for the data. I'm wondering if there is a method in sql or c# that can store the data in a personal database, then check (after a specified timeframe) whether or not there is new data at my 3rd party provider.

For example, instead of "calling the service"/"looking for the data" each time the page is loaded, I'd like to look for new data every week or so and store the data on a personal database to use for the next week. This helps me cut on the costs and also speeds up my system.

I'm not looking for any code here, just a simple way to execute/problem solve. My tools are VS, c#, SQL, asp.net/html.

Comment: It depends on the service you are using; their API might not support this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use sql dependency.  When the data has changed it will notify your application: [read more here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx) That is of course, if they allow it. You can also use any number of caching apps: AppFabric, memcached, SharedCache, ASP.NET cache.

Comment: thanks for this. do you have any specific details/examples for caching?

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458205/simple-c-asp-net-cache-implementation with asp.net cache object you can set the time limit for when an item will expire, you can also opt to use the aforementioned sqlcachedependency with it.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a simple table in SQL where you store the key you use to call the data provider, the data you last got back, and a timestamp when you last retrieved the data from your data provider.  If they key is not in your table, call your data provider and insert a row in the table with the result and a new timestamp.  If the timestamp is older than you would like (probably configure that amount of time in your web.config), retrieve the data and update that row in your table with the new data and new timestamp.

Make sure you're not violating the terms of service with your data provider by storing the data.  I work for a data provider and our contract allows for storing most data for a maximum of 24 hours.

Comment: Thanks Eric, is there a way to create and store timestamps within the .net framework? I've never done this before using sql-server or c#

Comment: You can set up triggers, etc, but the easiest way is simply to call the service from your app, get the data, and save it to the database specifying DateTime.Now (or UtcNow) as the timestamp. Any ORM you like will help you out both persisting the data and getting it back.

Comment: @cfarm54: Yes, it's easy to store things in SQL from the .NET framework.  There are a bunch of tutorials out there.  Here's the top google result: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/sql_in_csharp.aspx

Comment: It is not good practice to reinvent the wheel.  Using a proven solution would be much better than rolling ones own.

Comment: @subt13 are there any out there that I could just use?