# I am getting large json data from rest service

Tags: json, rest, service

I am getting large JSON data from rest service which is common to all users So I want to store these data in my server so that i don't make calls to the service again here my question is where should i store this data

1. application scope of web application
2. storing data in file
3. is there any caching technique ,please help me in this?

my server is web sphere portal

Comment: Better to place in application scope

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/41684599/1791065