# How to customize output cache action filter where it's cache by sql query in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sqlcachedependency

Is there any way to cache data based on SQL query for table in mvc

i have tried following filter and it successfully cache list based on taskId but now when any row changes which contain this taskid need to fetch data from table.

(Duration = 300, VaryByParam = "taskId", SqlDependency="taskHistorySqlDependency:tblProjectTaskHistory")]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looking for a very simple Cache example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41684213/looking-for-a-very-simple-cache-example)

Comment: @AndreiDragotoniu this is not the simple list caching. i need to cache list based on taskId which is done. but when any entry that contain taskId changed i want to refill  the list from table not from cache.